# How do I open a link in a new window (and all subsequent links in that same new window)?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app which I successfully got to segregate controllers for the hyperlinks to open windows and the target of the hyperlinks was successfully set as a new window.

My problem is, how do I only allocate one and only one window to open all new links, thereby preventing additional new windows from opening.

What I am suspecting is that I need window.location.href used in some way to modify the url location..

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You cannot

Use `target` attribute of the `a` element to open each time a new tab.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp):

```
|   Value   |  Description                                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| _blank    | Opens the linked document in a new window or tab        |
| _self     | Opens the linked document in the same frame (default)   |
| _parent   | Opens the linked document in the parent frame           |
| _top      | Opens the linked document in the full body of the window|
| framename |   Opens the linked document in a named frame            |
```

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/e5arnb61/

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.il/#q=search1" target="_blank">This alway open new tab</a>
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.co.il/#q=search2" target="_blank">This alway open new tab</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You set the target to any keywords other than `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, or `_top`. Then use that same name for any other links you want to target to this window and you're set.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_target.asp